# Problem with python and arduino in pyserial

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I wrote this code to print the sensor values ​​in Python, but the problem is that the soil_sensor prints twice.

This is the code in the Arduino :

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#define DHTPIN 8
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
int msensor = A0;
int msvalue = 0;
int min = 0;
int max = 1024;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(msensor, INPUT);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
    msvalue = analogRead(msensor);
  float percentage = (float)((msvalue - min) * 100) / (max - min);
  percentage = map(msvalue, max, min, 0, 100);
  Serial.print("r ");Serial.println(percentage);
   int h = dht.readHumidity();
   int t = dht.readTemperature();
   Serial.print ("h ");
   Serial.println (h);
   Serial.print ("c ");
   Serial.println (t);
  delay(2000);
}
```

And this is the code in Python :

```
from time import sleep
import serial

arduinoP1 = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600)

def rtot():
    arduino_data = arduinoP1.read(6)
    str_rn = arduino_data.decode()
    sleep(1)
    return str_rn
for x in range(3):
    i = rtot()
    if "r" in i:
        v1 = int(float(i[1:5].strip('\\r\\nr')))
        print(v1, 'soil_sensor')
    if "c" in i:
        print(i[1:2], 'temperature_sensor')
    if "h" in i:
        v3 = int(i[2:4])
        print(v3, 'Humidity_sensor')
```

As you can see, the soil sensor is repeated twice :
[soil sensor is repeated twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XzRJ.png)

I want the values ​​to be displayed correctly and in the form of numbers

Comment: You falsely assume the whole sent string will be only 6 bytes long and only contain data from a single sensor. And trying to read 3 sensors every 3 seconds, when they are sent every 2 seconds, won't work either.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: your output does not match your code. I would expect an error here. according to your output your soil_sensor value is 0. when you read the second set of 6 bytes you read something like `"\r\nh 60"` so you end up with `int("h ")` which will cause an error. please use hardcoded values and the actual output of that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should notice is that sending numbers throug the serial interface will result in different string lenghts depending on the number of digits.
So reading a fixed number of 6 bytes is not a good idea. (actually this is almost never a good idea)

You terminate each sensor reading with a linebreak. So why not use [readline](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline) instead of `read[6]`.

Here  `v1 = int(float(i[1:5].strip('\\r\\nr')))` you're trying to remove `\r`, `\n` and `r` from the received string. Unfortunately you escaped the backslash so you're actually stripping `\`, `r` and `n`.
`\r` is actually something where you need the backslash to represent the carriage return character. Don't escape it!

In the first run `loop()` will send something like:

`r 0.00\r\nh 40\r\nc 25\r\n`

So the first 6 bytes are `r 0.00`. So `i[1:5]` is  `0.0`.
As you see there is nothing to escape. Also 5 is excluded so you would have to use `i[2:6]` to get `0.00`. But as mentioned above using fixed lenghts for numbers is a bad idea. You can receive anything between `0.00` and `100.00` here.

So using readline you'll receive
`r 0.00\r\n`

The first and last two characters are always there and we can use `[2,-2]` to get the number inbetween regardless of its length.

Comment: I'm sorry my english is mediocre
What am I currently modifying in the code? I understand that I am helping the read to become a read line

Comment: yes you use [readline](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pyserial+readline) instead of read. once you have those lines you can extract the same string segment of each line to get the number string.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was supposed to focus more but I succeeded in the end and thank you again